# Section toggle hide and show in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I am trying to edit hide and show toggle in WordPress theme, in this theme when I click on map button footer section is going down and showing the map,

Now what I want is footer section will not go down and map will move upward side.

[image: screenshot]

Link: [theme link](http://demo.accesspressthemes.com/accesspress-parallax/)

Comment: Have you checked your console for JS errors? From what I've seen on the demo page, the button slides the map down, it's a jQuery function usually, so a error in the script might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is inside CSS file:

```
/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/style.css
```

You have to find .googlemap-toggle class property and change it from:

```
.googlemap-toggle {
   top: 0;
```

to

```
.googlemap-toggle {
   bottom: 0;
```

That's all you need to do.

Check CSS changes results video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfaKuvqtUAY